# "Baby Changing Table"

Tags: word-meaning

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changing_table), Changing Table refers a special table for a changing baby's nappy, and I have no problem with that.

However, I recently realized it is also called "Baby Changing Table", and I have a HUGE problem with that since I think it will sound better with "Nappy Changing Table" rather than baby changing table.

When I searched Google I can find those terms:

- "Baby Diaper Changing Tables"
- "Nappy Changing Tables"
- "Diaper Changing Tables"
- "Baby Changing Tables"

The first three mean: a changing table to change diapers.
However, the last one does not follow the same logic of the first three since "baby" is not equal to "diaper", "baby diaper" or "nappy".

I wonder if anyone also felt like I did, or anyone let me know how does it really sound.

Comment: Why is *nappy changing table* (and by implication, *baby changing table*) grammatically wrong, and why should anyone care if it is? Will everyone know what a nappy is, since some people call them diapers? How are you going to get your idea implemented if sufficient people agree that it is better? Finally, some people might prefer the term *baby changing table*, since it may give them some hope that they can exchange theirs for a less noisy model. The term *baby changing facilities* sounds almost ideal.

Comment: *sigh* there there. I deleted the sentence since that is not what I want to discuss.

Comment: It depends on where you are, I suppose. In the UK, "change the baby" is a well-understood idiom, and "baby-changing table" is unlikely to cause confusion, so I don't see any need for improvement.

Comment: If you learned that clothing stores have "changing rooms" for trying on clothes, would you likewise also have a huge problem with a store having a "customer changing room" and an "employee changing room"? The clothes are changed; the person is changing. The diaper is changed; the baby is changing (or being changed).

Comment: "Change the baby" is also a well-understood idiom in American English. Not clear why Kim (or anyone else) should have "a HUGE problem with that"?  What other logical meanings of "change the baby" or "baby changing" could there possibly be?

Comment: @JeremyDouglass It is interesting. I mean when I search Google for that I can see women*'s* changing room not women changing room. Likewise, Baby's changing room is perfectly fine for me since it does not sound like people swaps their babies. But, I do not believe the language does need to be so logical.

Comment: When language isn't logical, we call that "idiomatic". _Change the baby_ is a good example; we don't really swap children, but it's a shortened form of _change the baby's diaper_.

Comment: The manufacturer of baby foods whom I knew well told me once that he had taken the picture of a smiling baby off the label of his products lest his third-world customers mistake the publicity for the contents.

Comment: @Kim  This is a good example of English ambiguity, which is the kind of thing that keeps many comedians in business.  It  is hilarious because, yes, you're not changing the **baby** -- even though some new, exhausted parents wouldn't mind changing their baby for one who slept more and pooped less  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a place where babies could get their diapers changed. It's the same as a "changing place" - but for babies. It's not like it could be used for changing babies themselves. Read it as "Baby **Changing Tables**" (changing tables for babies) instead of "**Baby Changing** Tables" and you should be fine.

Comment: If you check the third comment on the question, @Mick states that *Baby-Changing* Table is unlikely to cause confusion. Then do you think Mick is wrong?

Comment: @Kim the question is more whether you think anyone would *reasonably* assume the table is meant to change one baby for another baby.  Since that would be silly, even though the expression seems *wrong*, it's still clearly a "diaper-changing" table no matter what it's called.  (FYI in AmE they're "diapers" and not "nappies".)